# Snowflake Regular Expression query

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, nsregularexpression

I need help with the regular expression to find a string starting with a specific word, in example below 'ABC' and then the numbers followed by that and ignore anything in between.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE "SCOPS_DB"."SCOPS_POLARIS_STG".TEST_REGEX  
( mystring varchar(10) );
 
INSERT INTO mytable values ('ABC ID :1234'); 
INSERT INTO mytable> values ('XYZABC6789'); 
INSERT INTO mytable> values ('qwe ABC-3456');
```

| Expected Result |
| --- |
| ABC1234 |
| ABC6789 |
| ABC3456 |

Answer (score 1):

So a deconstructed answer, showing how it works is:

```
SELECT column1
    ,regexp_substr(column1,'ABC')||regexp_substr(column1,'\\d+') as pankaj_answer
    ,regexp_count(column1, '(ABC)[^\\d]*(\\d+)$') as rc
    ,REGEXP_substr(column1, '(ABC)[^\\d]*(\\d+)$', 1, 1,'e', 1) as p1
    ,REGEXP_substr(column1, '(ABC)[^\\d]*(\\d+)$', 1, 1,'e', 2) as p2
    ,iff(rc=1, p1 || p2, null)
FROM values
    ('ABC'),
    ('123'),
    ('123-ABC'),
    ('ABC ID :1234'),
    ('XYZABC6789'),
    ('qwe ABC-3456');
```

gives:

| COLUMN1 | PANKAJ_ANSWER | RC | P1 | P2 | IFF(RC=1, P1 || P2, NULL) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | null | 0 | null | null | null |
| 123 | null | 0 | null | null | null |
| 123-ABC | ABC123 | 0 | null | null | null |
| ABC ID :1234 | ABC1234 | 1 | ABC | 1234 | ABC1234 |
| XYZABC6789 | ABC6789 | 1 | ABC | 6789 | ABC6789 |
| qwe ABC-3456 | ABC3456 | 1 | ABC | 3456 | ABC3456 |

which can be pushed together as:

```
SELECT column1
    ,iff(regexp_count(column1, '(ABC)[^\\d]*(\\d+)$')=1, 
         REGEXP_substr(column1, '(ABC)[^\\d]*(\\d+)$', 1, 1,'e', 1) || REGEXP_substr(column1, '(ABC)[^\\d]*(\\d+)$', 1, 1,'e', 2), 
         null) as answer
FROM values
    ('ABC'),
    ('123'),
    ('123-ABC'),
    ('ABC ID :1234'),
    ('XYZABC6789'),
    ('qwe ABC-3456');
```

| COLUMN1 | ANSWER |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | null |
| 123 | null |
| 123-ABC | null |
| ABC ID :1234 | ABC1234 |
| XYZABC6789 | ABC6789 |
| qwe ABC-3456 | ABC3456 |

Answer (score 0):

One approach can be as follows,
though I am sure there would be other approaches too using regex.

```
with data_cte (col) as
(select * from values
('ABC ID :1234'),
('XYZABC6789'),
('qwe ABC-3456')
)select concat(regexp_substr(col,'ABC'),
regexp_substr(col,'\\d+')) result
from data_cte ;
```

| RESULT |
| --- |
| ABC1234 |
| ABC6789 |
| ABC3456 |